# what is OOG transactions

Tags: transactions, out-of-gas

I am reading about the problem that happened today between geth and parity and i've found this qualification OOG transaction, what is it? 
https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5eoaaw/consensus_flaw_in_geth_we_have_identified_the/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means the transaction runs **out of gas**